# Cloning a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following table

```
<table id="customFields" class="table table-bordered table-hover additionalMargin alignment">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
        <th>Some Title</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><label class="subjectline" for="User1">User NOC M1</label></td>
            <td id="slLabel">SLA</td>
            <td id="slInput"><input type="text" name="slOptions[User][NOC M1]" class="form-control" id="User1"></td>
            <td><a class="addCF" href="javascript:void(0);">+ additional user</a></td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I then have the following javascript to add additional rows

```
$(function() {
    $(".addCF").click(function(){
        $("#customFields").append('<tr><td></td><td>SL_B</td> <td><input type="text" name="slOptions[User][NOC M1]" class="form-control" id="User1"></td> <td> &nbsp; <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
    });
    $("#customFields").on('click','.remCF',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
```

This currently works how I want it to.  However, there are a couple of things I am having issues with.

Firstly, when you first view it, you will see the label SL_A.  In the cloned version, I manually set it to SL_B.  All other clones then have SL_B.  What I am trying to do is have SL_ followed by the next letter in the alphabet.  So the third row should be SL_C.  I am not too sure how I can achieve this.

My second issue relates to the name of the cloned input.  At the moment, they all have the same name e.g. `slOptions[User][NOC M1]`
When a new row is added, the name should change to something unique, maybe using the additional letter of the alphabet above e.g. `slOptions[User][NOC M1B]`

Would it be possible to achieve these things?

I have set up a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zwf9njr/1/) for demonstration

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store a reference to the possible letters as well as your current letter and then within your function determine the appropriate one to use :

```
// Store the possible letters
var possibleLetters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
// Store the current letter
var currentLetter = 'A';

$(function() {
    $(".addCF").click(function(){
        // Resolve the next letter to add
        var nextIndex = possibleLetters.indexOf(currentLetter) + 1;
        // Update your reference
        currentLetter = possibleLetters[nextIndex];
        // Append it
        $("#customFields").append('<tr><td></td><td>SL_' + currentLetter + '</td> <td><input type="text" name="slOptions[User][NOC M1' + currentLetter + ']"...');
        // More code omitted for brevity
    });
    // Still more code omitted for brevity
});
```

You can [see an example of this in action here](https://jsfiddle.net/xhjdcthL/) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: Thank you, works great. One question, if I add a row, making it SL_B, and then remove that row, and then readd it then it has SL_C. Is it possible to make it have SL_B again? Thanks

Comment: Sure, you would likely just need to adjust your remove button to push the previous letter back [similar to this approach](https://gist.github.com/Rionmonster/745bd50a900c541f0e83d0df0c223cd5). Another approach still would be to store two arrays with the letters that were in use and those that were out of use so that you could determine which were removed and then reuse them as expected. It ultimately depends on your preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution for both the issues:
See: https://jsfiddle.net/pdxgrpqz/

```
$(function() {
    alp = "A";
    $(".addCF").click(function(){
    alp = (alp.substring(0,alp.length-1)+String.fromCharCode(alp.charCodeAt(alp.length-1)+1));
    $("#customFields").append('<tr><td></td><td>SL_'+alp+'</td> <td><input type="text" name="slOptions[User][NOC M1'+alp+']" class="form-control" id="User1"></td> <td> &nbsp; <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
    });
    $("#customFields").on('click','.remCF',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, works great.  One question, if I add a row, making it SL_B, and then remove that row, and then readd it then it has SL_C.  Is it possible to make it have SL_B again?  Thanks

Comment: I think you will need to reset the names of td lable in that case..thats only solution i can think..